# Saving Pending Notifications to an Array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to save all of the scheduled local notifications to an array to be read from and referenced again later on in the code. This is the code I'm trying to use to save all of the notifications:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    var test: [UNNotificationRequest] = []
    
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
        for item in notifications {
            test.append(item)
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, my test array remains empty despite the fact that I have 4 scheduled notifications. When I step through the debugger, I can see that it finds all of the notifications. It's just not saving them.

Comment: `getPendingNotificationRequests` gets called asynchronously. My assumption you try to read the `test` variable right after this method is called, but instead you have to wait until callback is finished and ensure that your `test` array can survive long enough to remain relevant

Comment: Yep, that was it. test was out of scope before it was even assigned.